# Query only creating 7 out of 10 tables.. assistance please?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have designed this query to create 10 tables - however it creates 7 and then stops. Im not sure why. I have exhausted all I know to look for. Here is the script - any help would be appreciated.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY';

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CUSTOMER_ID INTEGER,
CUST_FNAME VARCHAR2(20),
CUST_LANME VARCHAR2(20),
CUST_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(20),
CUST_CITY VARCHAR2(20),
CUST_ZIPCODE VARCHAR2(10),
CUST_STATE VARCHAR2(15),
CUST_PHONE VARCHAR2(15),
CUST_EMAIL VARCHAR2(35),
CUST_cODE INTEGER,
POLICY_NUMBER VARCHAR2(20));

/* -- */

CREATE TABLE VEHICLE(
VIN_NUMBER VARCHAR2(30),
MANUFACTURER VARCHAR2(20),
MAKE VARCHAR2(15),
MODEL VARCHAR2(15),
YEAR VARCHAR2(4),
MILEAGE VARCHAR2(7),
CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR2(10));


/* -- */

CREATE TABLE PART(
PART_ID VARCHAR2(20),
PART_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(35),
PART_ORGIN_PRICE NUMBER(10),
SUPPL_ID INTEGER);


/* -- */


CREATE TABLE PAYMENT(
PAYMT_ID VARCHAR2(15),
PAYMT_DATE DATE,
PAYMENT_METHOD VARCHAR2(10),
COMP_CODE INTEGER,
CUSOTMER_ID INTEGER,
BILL_NUMBER INTEGER);

/* -- */

CREATE TABLE REPAIR_LINE(
BILL_NUMBER INTEGER,
VIN_NUMBER INTEGER,
REPAIR_CODE INTEGER,
START_TIME DATE,
END_TIME DATE,
PARTS VARCHAR2(25),
EMP_ID INTEGER,
PART_ID INTEGER,
PART_PRICE NUMBER(10));


/* -- */

CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER(
SUPPL_ID INTEGER,
SUPPLY_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
SUPPLY_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(20),
SUPPLY_CITY VARCHAR2(20),
SUPPLY_ZIPCODE VARCHAR2(10),
SUPPLY_STATE VARCHAR2(15),
SUPPLY_EMAIL VARCHAR2(35),
SUPPLY_PHONE VARCHAR2(20));



/* -- */

CREATE TABLE INSURANCE(
COMP_CODE INTEGER,
COMP_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
COMP_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(20),
COMP_CITY VARCHAR2(20),
COMP_ZIPCODE VARCHAR2(10),
COMP_STATE VARCHAR2(15),
COMP_EMAIL VARCHAR2(35),
AGENT_PHONE VARCHAR2(20));


/* -- */

CREATE TABLE BILL(
BILL_NUMBER INTEGER,
BILL_DATE DATE,
B_AMOUNT_INSURED NUMBER(10),
B_AMOUNT_CUST NUMBER(10),
bILL_STATUS VARCHAR2(15));


/* -- */

CREATE TABLE REPAIR(
BILL_NUMBER INTEGER,
REPAIR_CODE INTEGER,
DATE DATE,
LABOR NUMBER,
TAX_RATE NUMBER,
TOT_BEFORETAX NUMBER,
TOTAL NUMBER(10),
REPAIR_TYPE VARCHAR2(15));

/* -- */

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
EMP_ID INTERGER,
EMP_FNAME VARCHAR2(25),
EMP_LNAME VARCHAR2(25),
EMP_ADDRESS VARCHAR2(20),
EMP_CITY VARCHAR2(20),
EMP_ZIPCODE VARCHAR2(10),
EMP_STATE VARCHAR2(15),
EMP_EMAIL VARCHAR2(35),
EMP_PAYRATE NUMBER(10),
EMP_PHONE VARCHAR2(20));
```

/* -- */

Comment: At least two have keywords as column names, which won't work; `YEAR` and `DATE` (and maybe `MODEL`?). But is it creating the first 7? What errors do you get? Where are you running the script?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?  How are you connecting to the DB and running the script?  Is there perhaps already a BILL table?

Answer (score 2):

there are a couple of errors in the script:

```
in VEHICLE table, YEAR may be reserved word.  change it to something else.

in REPAIR table, DATE is a reserved word.  change it to something else.

in EMPLOYEE table, EMP_ID INTERGER ... spelling error.  change to INTEGER.
```

then, try it again.

Comment: `YEAR` actually isn't reserved, despite my earlier comment, but `DATE` is. Good spot on`INTERGER`.

Answer (score 1):

`DATE` is a [reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_keywd001.htm#BABCJAEB), so you can't use that as a column name, as you're trying to do in the `REPAIR` table. You'll get an ORA-00904, 'invalid identifier` error.

Your client should be telling you what errors are occurring. It isn't obvious why any of the others would have a problem; except, as BWS pointed out, you misspelled `INTERGER` (ORA-00902).  Showing the errors, or even which tables are and are not created, would help of course.